# Javascript: Moving object on canvas (trying to learn object oriented programming)

Tags: javascript, html, object, canvas, move

So basicly I want to make a simple Snake game, but I'm stuck already at the moving part.

This is the code that works if I make a button onclick = "snake.show()" and as I click the button, the rectangle moves. (snake.show() is also in the body onload)

```
    var width = 800;
    var height = 400;
    var x = width/2;
    var y = height/2;

    class Snake{
        show(){
            var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.rect(x, y, 20, 5);
            ctx.fill();
            x++;
        }
        //update(){}
    }

    let snake = new Snake();
```

but instead of that i want to make something like this:

```
    var width = 800;
    var height = 400;
    var x = width/2;
    var y = height/2;

    class Snake{
        show(){
            var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.rect(x, y, 20, 5);
            ctx.fill();
        }
        update(){
            x++;
        }
    }
```

And call the update() function if I need to move the rectangle, but this does not work. Sorry for my bad english, thanks for the advices and for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Declare the canvas and the context as global variables (only once).
2. A class need a constructor method.
3. I'm updating and showing again the snake  on keydown the right arrow.

I hope it helps.

```js
const c = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

const width = (c.width = 800);
const height = (c.height = 400);

class Snake {
  constructor() {
    this.x = width / 2;
    this.y = height / 2;
  }
  show() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 20, 5);
    ctx.fill();
  }
  update() {
    this.x+=20;
  }
}

let snake = new Snake();
snake.show();

window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    snake.update();
    snake.show();
  }
});
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: A class does need a constructor but you don't have to specify it yourself. A default constructor will be used if omitted.